# SQL Server Trigger is executing twice

Tags: sql-server-2008

Having very simple trigger...

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[DEL_NOT_ALLOWED_ON_USER_TBL]
ON [dbo].[USER_TBL]
FOR DELETE AS
BEGIN
        PRINT 'Sorry! - Delete Not Allowed!'
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        INSERT INTO WHO_TRIED_TO_DELETE_TABLE
        (DATE, DEL_TABLE_NAME, COMMENT)
        VALUES (GETDATE(), 'USER_TBL', 'STOPPED DUE TO TRIGGER ON USR TABLE')
        RETURN;
END
```

When someone tries to execute statement like following:

```
delete USER_TBL where 1 = 1 and user_id in ('john78rrt3458@yahoo.com') -- only 1 record found...
```

after that am finding two records in `WHO_TRIED_TO_DELETE_TABLE`

```
ROW_ID  DATE    DEL_TABLE_NAME  COMMENT
32  10/23/2015 5:52:09 PM   USER_TBL    STOPPED DUE TO TRIGGER ON USR TABLE
31  10/23/2015 5:52:09 PM   USER_TBL    STOPPED DUE TO TRIGGER ON USR TABLE
```

Any idea?

Why trigger is executing twice?

Comment: Please use the code formating (see toolbar above the text box, or manually by adding 4 white spaces in front of each code line).

Comment: Either 2 records that match that user_id or 2 triggers.

Comment: what is the result for select count(*) from USER_TBL where 1 = 1 and user_id in ('john78rrt3458@yahoo.com') ?

Comment: trigger runs per batch so doesn't matter. But to answer your question, only one record found in delete statement.

Answer (score 0):

1. 1-be sure that you don't have 2 triggers for Delete on USER_TBL
2. be sure that you don't have a trigger for insert on WHO_TRIED_TO_DELETE_TABLE
3. use sql server profiler for check what queries sent to dbms